# Windows Phone Emulator does not communicate with local WebAPI 2 services

Tags: asp.net-web-api, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2015, windows-phone-8.1, windows-10-mobile

I have a Windows Phone 8 App.  It uses a series of WebAPI 2 calls to retrieve data from the server.  In Visual Studio 2013 I can run the WebAPI project in Visual Studio and then run the App on an emulator through Visual Studio and everything works.  For this to work I do have to run Visual Studio 2013 as an Administrator and I had to add an extra line into the IISExpress applicationhost.config file under the API application's entry as seen below:

```
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:56952:192.168.1.59" />
```

This is the line of code in the App that sets the location of the WebAPIs:

public const string APIPrefix = "http://192.168.1.59:56952";

It does not matter if I run the app on a Windows Phone 8.1 Or Windows 10 Mobile emulator, as long as I am running through Visual Studio 2013 it connects to the WebAPI project I have running in Visual Studio.  Note that 192.168.1.59 is the IP address of my development machine where I am running Visual Studio.

When I upgrade the projects to Visual Studio 2015 and run everything the exact same way (run as administrator and the project names are exactly the same so I don't need to make a change to the applicationhost.config file) any call to a WebAPI returns the "Not Found" message.

Any idea what I am missing in Visual Studio 2015 to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did find a fix for this.  If I change the API Prefix from:

```
APIPrefix = "http://192.168.1.59:56952";
```

to

```
APIPrefix = "http://localhost:56952";
```

it seems work everywhere except on the Windows 10 Mobile emulator version 10.0.14393.0.  I have found the problem with that version of the emulator reported on another thread here

[Unable to access local Web API from Visual Studio 2015 WIndows 10 Phone Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41016341/unable-to-access-local-web-api-from-visual-studio-2015-windows-10-phone-emulator)

Hope this helps other people.